# When i change from matrix to data frame, values are changing in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, subtraction

I have a matrix which was read from file. And i am sure it consists of characters. This matrix has 4 columns which are called "type","time","x value","y value". And except "type" other 3 columns values' are numbers.

I want to do arithmetic operations like subtraction on time column. But it gives me :

**non-numeric argument to binary operator error**

My data is:

```
data <-as.matrix(read.table("data/firstdata.cal"))
```

Here is some content of my data

```
   Type     Time            X           Y
1   R   1383154550660   0.5638523   0.5157838
2   R   1383154550732   0.5637349   0.5152285
3   R   1383154550778   0.5634450   0.5154306
4   R   1383154550872   0.5631472   0.5145780
5   R   1383154550922   0.5633539   0.5150688
6   R   1383154550984   0.5630451   0.5148284
```

I change its class to data frame by writing:

```
data<-as.data.frame(data)
data[, 2] <- as.numeric(as.character( data[, 2] ))
```

Then i want to do subtraction between rows like this:

```
i<-1
output<-matrix(0,nrow(data),ncol(data))

while(data[i,1]!='SS')
i<-i+1
temp<-0
while(i<nrow(data)){
if(data[i,1]=='SS'){
  temp<-data[i,3]
  output[i+1,1]<-temp
  n<-n-1
}
else {
  j<-i+1
  while(data[j,2]-data[i,2]<=700 )
  { 
    j<-j+1
  }  
  k<-0
  while (data[j,2]-data[i,2]<=2000){

    output[k,3]<-data[i,3]
    output[k,2]<-temp
    output[k,1]<-data[j,2]-data[i,2]
    j<-j+1
    k<-k+1
  }

}
i<-i+1 
}
```

But the values before changing to data frame and after changing the data frame are different. So, what should i do to get original values without getting error?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I've put my data here @DavidArenburg

Comment: So what is the purpose of the `while` loop and what is different regarding the values? Also, why are you converting to a matrix using `as.matrix`? This is a bad practice if you have column from different classes. This is what data frames for.

Comment: As i added rest of code, this is for writing to new matrix which is called output. I want to get ones whose difference between 700-2000 from first point then assign to new matrix..

Comment: First don't use `as.matrix` when reading, just do `data <-read.table("data/firstdata.cal")`. Second, please provide your desired output as I find it hard to debug your `while` loop.

Comment: Like you said i remove as.matrix and now it is better. Thank you

Comment: @Gunner1905, FYI: it's doing this because a `matrix` is by its definition a structure where ***all elements are the same type***. If you convert a data.frame of all numbers to a matrix, then you're okay. However, if even one of the data.frame columns is a string, all other elements are "up-converted" to a string. So: data.frame allows different type columns, matrix does not. As @DavidArenburg was saying, it's generally bad practice to blindly convert between data.frames and matrices: it will almost always bite you at some point, as you have found :-)